# Two javascript conditions instructed with ternary operators not working at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script creates different dialog boxes with jQuery depending on the data stored in an array, using ternary operator:

```
$div.html(data).dialog({
    dialogClass: array[current][5] == 4 ?
                    "green" :
                    array[current][5] == 3 ?
                        "green" :
                        array[current][5] == 0 ?
                            "red" :
                            "orange",
    width:"750px",
    title: array[current][5] == 4 ?
                "Ok" :
                array[current][5] == 3 ?
                    "Ok" :
                    array[current][5] == 0 ?
                        "Bad" :
                        "Average",
    position: {my: "center top",
               at: "center top",
               of: "#doc-frame"},
    buttons: {
        'Previous': function() {
            if (current == 0) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                current--;
            }

            $(this).dialog("close").remove();
            createDialog(array[current][0], current);
        },
        'Next': function() {
            if (current == (array.length - 1)) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                current++;
            }

            $(this).dialog("close").remove();
            createDialog(array[current][0], current);
        }
    }
});
```

For some reasons, the change of title does not work. But it works when I comment out the dialogClass line (I do not change the style/format of the dialog box). Does anyone know why both conditions (dialogClass and title) do not work together and what is the right syntax to have both working at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what those variables refer to. Create a [mcve] demo

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object instead of the ternary construct.

```
var values = {
    4: { color: 'green', title: 'Ok' },
    3: { color: 'green', title: 'Ok' },
    0: { color: 'red', title: 'Bad' },
    default: { color: 'orange', title: 'Average' }
};
```

usage

```
dialogClass: (values[array[current][5]] || values.default).color,
title:       (values[array[current][5]] || values.default).title,
```